# Google Chrome: "java plugin is out of date" issue

Tags: google-chrome, java, browser-plugin

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Browser: Google Chrome
Plugin: Java

Issue is regarding the java plugin, a message shows up at top of screen that Plugin is out of date even when i have latest java installed on my laptop. How can i fix this issue? and why is it prompting to update when it is already up to date.

Comment: Is it chrome 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: @ohope5 its chrome 32